# Resurrect A Lost Religion

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I founded a religion in my capital (Buddhism).  After another civilization converted my city to their religion, I used an [Inquisitor](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisitor_(Civ5)), thinking it would remove the other civilization's religion.  However, I was wrong.... ***very wrong***.  Now, when I refer to my Religion Overview, it turns out no other cities/city-states follow Buddhism, so clearly my religion `did not stand the test of time`.

*Question:* 
Is it possible to resurrect a religion?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!